# How to import a MS SQL server table into mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-server-2008

I need to export about 300,000 rows from a table on MS SQL server and import into mysql on a different server (non windows).
There is some text stored in some fields and commas in the text will mess up the format if I export into txt format.

I can't install any software on the server.

Comment: Can you dump your schema and data in ANSI SQL? I'm not familiar with Microsoft product.

Comment: If you can access SQL Server and MySQL from another host, then try Data Import tool (use ODBC connection for SQL Server) - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have several options:

- use SSIS or DTS Wizard on another host to interconnect MSSQL and MySQL
- write your own small app to move the data
- script the MSSQL DB's **DATA** into script file with SSMS' scripting features, adopt the script manually to mysql and run it

Comment: thanks for the help. If I export to Excel format I can import into mysql and don't have problems with commas. It also gives me a good tool to scrub and clean the data prior to the import

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can connect to MySQL from SSIS. I'd go down that route.